# Unregister/delete users from Yodlee sandbox environment when I don't have the credentials

Tags: yodlee

I have created a number of test users in our Yodlee private sandbox environment but now I want to remove them. I do not have the usernames/passwords for these users any more.

Is there a way to delete them? Do I *need* to delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to raise a request to Yodlee support to get all those users deleted.